# How to enforce a security policy for each and every executing java program

Tags: java, jvm, security-policy

How can i specify a security policy for a JVM that will be applied to every program executed inside it.

Answer (score 1):

Update the default java security policy file for the JVM:

```
https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/security/PolicyFiles.html
```

Alternatively if you want a different policy file for each application, you need to define the policy on startup by adding the following setting to the java command:

```
-Djava.security.manager -Djava.security.policy=/path/to/app.policy
```